# scatter update tensor with index obtained using argmax

Tags: python, tensorflow, reinforcement-learning

I'm trying to update a tensor's max value with another value, like so:

```
actions = tf.argmax(output, axis=1)
gen_targets = tf.scatter_nd_update(output, actions, q_value)
```

I'm getting an error: `AttributeError: 'Tensor' object has no attribute 'handle'` on `scatter_nd_update`.

The `output` and `actions` are placeholders declared as:

```
output = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, num_action])
reward = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None])
```

What am I doing wrong and what would be the correct way to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are trying to update the value of `output` which is of type `tf.placeholder`. Placeholders are immutable objects, you cannot update the value of the placeholder. The tensor you are trying to update should be of type of a variable, e.g. [tf.Variable](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/Variable), in order for [tf.scatter_nd_update()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/scatter_nd_update) to be able to update its value.
One way to solve this could be to create a variable and then assign the value of the placeholder to the variable using [tf.assign()](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/assign). Since one of the dimensions of the placeholder is `None` and may be of arbitrary size during runtime, you may want to set `validate_shape` argument of `tf.assign()` to `False`, this way the shape of the placeholder does not need to match the shape of the variable. After the assignment, the shape of `var_output` will match the actual shape of the object that was fed via the placeholder.

```
output = tf.placeholder('float', shape=[None, num_action])
# dummy variable initialization
var_output = tf.Variable(0, dtype=output.dtype)

# assign value of placeholder to the var_output
var_output = tf.assign(var_output, output, validate_shape=False)
# ...
gen_targets = tf.scatter_nd_update(var_output, actions, q_value)
# ...
sess.run(gen_targets, feed_dict={output: feed_your_placeholder_here})
```

Comment: How do I set the shape of `var_output` variable to match the shape of the `output` placeholder? Especially since the shape of the placeholder has a `None` to account for varying batch sizes.